# SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) versus User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

The default `_LoginPartial.cshtml` provided by Asp.net Core web application template is as follows.

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post">
        <ul >
            <li>
                <a asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit">Log out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul >
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Rather than using the injected `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)`, why don't we use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` that is much simpler? Is there any difference that I have not noticed yet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`IsAuthenticated` works on all types of `ClaimsPrincipals`, which may come from ASP.NET Core Identity, or Social authentication, or AAD, or WS-Fed or whatever else.

`IsSignedIn` is very specific to ASP.NET Identity.

If you are only using ASP.NET Identity stick to `IsSignedIn`. If you're writing an app that can use other types of authentication then use `IsAuthenticated`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help shed some light on the difference - https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1538

Basically, as per MS `SignInManager` is part of the identity framework whereas `IsAuthenticated` is just one component. Based on this issue, it seems like `IsAuthenticated` can give you some incorrect results.

Comment: So it means that `IsAuthenticated` must not be used anymore, right?

Comment: My assumption would be that `IsAuthenticated` may be set to true before all claims that indicate a successful "sign-in" are set (think OIDC flows).

Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.issignedin?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_IsSignedIn_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_

I think the key statement is logged in (authenticated) WITH identity.